# How to test if watching a advertisement only 1 time is enough to change one's preference

Tags: binomial-distribution, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test, mcnemar-test

I'm sort of having a trouble finding what statistical test to use in a specific project of mine.

My experiment was as follows:

I have 10 friends and they all prefer Coke cola then Pepsi.
Each of them bought Coke or Pepsi once for almost every day.
To measure the preference, I investigated the their purchase over 5 days.
(C = coke, P = pepsi, x = No purchase)

```
       Day: 1 2 3 4 5
```

- **Friend A** : C P P C C  ( = 2/5)
- **Friend B** : C C C P C  ( = 1/5)
- **Friend C** : C C P C P  ( = 2/5)
- **Friend D** : C C P **x** C  ( = 1/4)
- **Friend E** : C C C C C  ( = 0/5)
- **Friend F** : C P P C C  ( = 2/5)
- **Friend G** : C C C **x** C  ( = 0/4)
- **Friend H** : C C P C P  ( = 2/5)
- **Friend I** : C C P C C  ( = 1/5)
- **Friend J** : C **x** C C C  ( = 0/4)

---

- In total,  they bought Pepsi only 10 out of 47 times (21%). (I excluded no-purchase-numbers from computing the proportion.)

Then at the morning of 6th day, I showed them Pepsi advertisement a single time.
My hypothesis is that, even a single view could change the Preference.

In Result, 5 out of them bought Pepsi that day (83%), 1 bought coke (17%), and 4 did not buy anything. (I excluded No-purchase-numbers from computing proportion as in last 5 days.)

I was trying to use Binomial test with expected proportion of 21% to test if 5 out of 6 (83%) is significantly different from last five days, but I'm unsure if this would be the correct way.
I've also considered Fisher exact Test (or Mcnemar Test), but since my data is partially paired and contains repeated measure over 5 days, both of them seemed inappropriate.

ps: I've also conducted 3 control tests using 3 different advertisements of other products, and all of them did not increase the pepsi-purchase-rate.

Would using the binomial test be right? Or am I doing this completely wrong? Is there a better way? Please help..

Comment: In the first place, these friends are not a random sample of any population, and in all likelihood not independent. Tests aim at making statements about "true" values in a bigger population. I don't think any test would allow you to make such a claim based on these data (apart from not being clear what that population might be).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. But  in the actual experimental setting, subjects were sampled randomly, and could be considered independent. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe a better way of putting this is to say that readers are asked to assume random sampling and independence as this is what you're interested in. For the setup you describe this is hard to believe, but I don't think that discussing this is what you want. (By the way whatever is dependent "could be considered independent", but the result of this may not be any good.)

Comment: I agree. Maybe I should’nt have used the analogy as it just gives confusion. Thanks for the advice
This is actually an animal study, so I considered subjects as random sample of whole population and each choice was made in seperate enviroment from other subjects, in seperate time. I hope this solves the indepedency problem.

Comment: I think you could apply a technique from Bayesian statistics called "switchpoint" tests (beasically these tests figure out exactly what you need: do customers change their behaviour at the switchpoint when they are exposed to something?). See https://camdavidsonpilon.github.io/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/#examples ... maybe "Simpler AB Testing" could fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I’ll check out!